# Optaplanner to solve waste collection problem

Tags: optaplanner

Can Optaplanner be used to solve the waste collection problem? The waste collection trucks will need to go to the dump site when full and then return to collect from the remaining locations.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly. Check the vehicle routing examples provided with Optaplanner. Waste collection is a very similar problem. You want to maximize the collected waste while minimizing transportation cost (distance driven, number of vehicles used...).

In contrast to the VRP here you do not *deliver* goods starting from the depot fully loaded - instead, the vehicles depart empty from the depot and then *pickup* waste until their capacity limit is reached and then return to the depot/dump site.

Comment: What if the dump site is not the starting depot site and there are more than one dump sites and the truck goes to the nearest dump site when full? How are the trips to the different dump sites added when the data is only the list of waste pickup locations/quantities?

Comment: To add to this, the waste collection problem is a flavour of the vrp with multiple trips (as per the description). See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952131/what-is-the-best-practice-for-solving-vrpmt-problem-with-optaplanner

Comment: In waste collection, often the pickups aren't modeled per house, but per road segment (basically one side of a road between 2 intersections with no intersections in between). So vehicles go from road section to road section in the model (instead of from house to house like in reality). That reduces the search space - and still works in reality.